# highcharts multiple charts with the same x data(timerange) with cross x,y lines

Tags: highcharts

Can I create highcharts multiple charts with the same x data(timerange) that have a cross x and Y chooser/selector?

I'd to be able to select an area across the charts - see attached image.
In the attached, note that the time range is the same across the different countries

Blue lines - show the xy cursor location 
Black rectangle - the selected area

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPL5u.png)

Comment: You can enabled crosshairs by the option: http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#tooltip.crosshairs

Comment: Does crosshairs works across multiple charts (same type - see attached image) as it was one chart?

Comment: So the crosshair should be visible in the single pane? Defaulty is on mutliple axis like here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! but what I meant is to have for all the charts a connected line across them, like it was one chart

Comment: But in this demo, crosshair (line) is printed in all charts...Im confused a bit

Comment: Have a look on the above attached image "example", as you can see each one of the countries is a different chart and above all of them there are the X,Y blue lines that behave like it was one chart, I hope now it clear